# Token is not defined - MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, mean-stack

I've been following a book tutorial called mean machine. It has been super helpful. I am  setting up authentication and can't figure out this error I'm getting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can't seem to find the answer anywhere else.

ERROR: token is not defined
    at Object.authTokenFactory.setToken (authService.js:69)

authService.js:

```js
angular.module('authService', [])

// ===================================================
// auth factory to login and get information
// inject $http for communicating with the API
// inject $q to return promise objects
// inject AuthToken to manage tokens
// ===================================================

.factory('Auth', function($http, $q, AuthToken) {
 // create auth factory obj
 var authFactory = {};
 // login user
 authFactory.login = function(username, password) {
  // return promise obj and its data
  return $http.post('/api/authenticate', {
   username: username,
   password: password
  })
  .success(function(data) {
   AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
   return data;
  });
 };
 
 // logout user by clearing token
 authFactory.logout = function() {
  AuthToken.setToken();
 };
 
 // check if user is logged in
 // checks for local token
 authFactory.isLoggedIn = function() {
  if (AuthToken.getToken())
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 };
 
 // get logged in user
 authFactory.getUser = function() {
  if (AuthToken.getToken())
   return $http.get('/api/me', { cache : true});
  else
   return $q.reject({ message : 'User has no token.'});
 };
 
 
 
 return authFactory;
})
// ===================================================
// factory for handling tokens
// inject $window to store token client-side
// 
// 
// ===================================================
.factory('AuthToken', function($window) {
 var authTokenFactory = {};
 
 // get token out of local storage
 authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {
  return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
 };
 // function to set token or clear token
  // if a token is passed, set the token
  // if there is no token, clear it from local storage
  authTokenFactory.setToken = function() {
   if (token)
    $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  else
   $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
  };
 
 return authTokenFactory;
})
// ===================================================
// application configuration to integrate token into requests
// ===================================================
.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {
 var interceptorFactory = {};
 
 // this will happen on all http requests
 interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
  // grab token
  var token = AuthToken.getToken;
  // if token exists add it to the header as x-access-token
  if (token)
   config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
   
   return config;
 };
 
 // happens on response errors
 interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {
  // if 403 from server
  if (response.status == 403) {
   AuthToken.setToken();
   $location.path('/login')
  }
  //return the errors from server as promise
  return $q.reject(response);
 };
 
 return interceptorFactory;
});
```

mainCtrl.js

```js
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])
.controller('MainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
 var vm = this;
 
 // get info if a person is logged in
 vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
 
 // check to see if user is logged in on every req
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
  vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();
  
  // get user info on route change
  // Auth.getUser()
  // .success(function(data) {
  //  vm.u = data;
  // });
  Auth.getUser().then(function (data) {
       vm.user = data;
  },
  function (response) {
   // Handle case where user is not logged in
   // or http request fails
  });
 });
 
 // handle login form
 vm.doLogin = function () {
  vm.processing = true;
  // clear error
  vm.error = '';
  
  // call Auth.login() func
  Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
   .success(function(data) {
    vm.processing = false;
    //if a user logs in, redirect to users pg
    if (data.success)
     $location.path('/users');
    else 
     vm.error = data.message;
    
    
   });
 };
 
 // log out
 vm.doLogOut = function() {
  Auth.logout();
  vm.u = {};
  $location.path('/login');
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you've received really says it all. The `token` variable is never defined in `authTokenFactory.setToken()`.

```
authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {  // Add this variable delcaration
    if (token)
        $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    else
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    };
 }
```

Comment: This is happening after I submit my login form.

I'm not too sure why it wouldnt be set :/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by // Add this variable delcaration

Comment: In your code, setToken is not accepting any parameters. You need to add token as a parameter to the function.